# Как правильно сделать клик в клике?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть input с автокомплитом. В автокомплите структара данных:

```
<div id="suggesstion-box">
    <ul id="country-list">
        <li onclick="selectCountry('Пара-Чинар (Пакистан) регламент 50 мин '); ">Пара-Чинар (Пакистан)
            <span class="test-li" li-data="Пара-Чинар" span-data="244"></span>
        </li>

        <li onclick="selectCountry('Параку (Бенин) регламент 50 мин '); ">Параку (Бенин)
            <span class="test-li" li-data="Параку" span-data="244"></span>
        </li>

        <li onclick="selectCountry('Парапарауму (Новая Зеландия) регламент 90 мин '); ">
            Парапарауму (Новая Зеландия)
            <span class="test-li" li-data="Парапарауму" span-data="246"></span>
        </li>

        <li onclick="selectCountry('Параси (Соломоновы острова) регламент 90 мин '); ">
            Параси (Соломоновы острова)
            <span class="test-li" li-data="Параси" span-data="246"></span>
        </li>

        <li onclick="selectCountry('Паратебуэно (Колумбия) регламент 50 мин '); ">
            Паратебуэно (Колумбия)
            <span class="test-li" li-data="Паратебуэно" span-data="244"></span>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#country-list li').click(function (){
  var test = $(this).find('span').attr('span-data');
  alert (test);
});
```

Всё отрабатывает хорошо, я получаю span-data кликнутого элемента. Дальше есть кнопка продолжить, после которой нужно выводить эту span-data.

Как мне сделать клик в клике? 
Например код не сработает. Прошу помочь

```
$("#airports_next").click(function () {
  $('#country-list li').click(function (){
    var test = $(this).find('span').attr('span-data');
    alert (test);
  });
});
```

Comment: вы тут не делаете "клик в клике" а назначаете обработчик в обработчике.

Comment: если вам надо вызвать назначенный обработчик тогда и вызовите `.click()` или `trigger('click')`

Comment: не совсем понимаю как реализовать. 

$("#airports_next").click(function () {
  $('#country-list li').trigger(function (){
    var test = $(this).find('span').attr('span-data');
    alert (test);
  });
});

Comment: @Martovytskyi разделите 2 обработчика и в клике next вызываете клик. Желательно, скиньте полную структуру, включая input и кнопку #airports_next

Comment: https://codepen.io/webneed2016/pen/XWWMera вот структура. Разделял на 2 обработчика, получаю рандомный span-data